# How to create,edit and delete data in Ng2 smart table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I used [ng2 smart table] in my angular 2 project, I need to send an API request using http.post() method but the problem happened when I click on the button to confirm data face this error in console:

> ERROR TypeError: _co.addClient is not a function.

this is code in **service.ts** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Clients } from './clients.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientsService {

  url="http://localhost:21063/api/clints"
  clients:Clients[];
  client:Clients;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
getAllClients(): Observable<Clients[]>{
    return this.http.get<Clients[]>(this.url);

}
addClient(event){
this.http.post<Clients>(this.url,this.client)
.subscribe(
  res=>{
    console.log(res);

    event.confirm.resolve(event.Clients);
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.error instanceof Error) {
      console.log("Client-side error occurred.");
    } else {
      console.log("Server-side error occurred.");
    }
  }
)
}
```

and this my **template** :

```
        <div class="mainTbl">

            <ng2-smart-table 
            [settings]="settMain" 
            [source]="this.Service.clients"
            (createConfirm)="addClient($event)"
            (editConfirm)="onEditConfirm($event)"
            (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)"
            ></ng2-smart-table>

        </div>
```

**compontent .ts**

```
settMain = {
    noDataMessage: 'عفوا لا توجد بيانات',

    actions: {
      columnTitle: 'إجراءات',
      position: 'right',
    },
    pager: {
      perPage: 5,
    },
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '  إضافة جديد ',
      createButtonContent: '',
      cancelButtonContent: '',
      confirmCreate: true,
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '',
      saveButtonContent: '',
      cancelButtonContent: '',
      confirmSave: true,


    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '',
      confirmDelete: true,
    },

    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'كود العميل',
        width: '80px',
      },
      name: {
        title: 'اسم العميل',
        width: '160px'
      },
      phone: {
        title: ' الهاتف'
      },
      address: {
        title: ' العنوان'
      },
      account: {
        title: 'الرصيد '
      },
      notes: {
        title: 'ملاحظات'
      }
    }
  };


  private myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private Service: ClientsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.Service.getAllClients().subscribe(data => this.Service.clients = data);
    this.Service.client={
      id:0,
      name:null,
      phone:null,
      address:null,
      type:null,
      account:0,
      nots:null,
      branchId:0,
    };
```

so how can I find my mistake also what the best way to handle create, edit and delete operations?
 thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `addClient` is a method on `service.ts`, whereas the `ng2-smart-table` is instantiated on that component, and you shouldn't directly call your service method on the template.

Therefore, the right way of doing things would be to create a method on your component.ts which calls the `addClient` method.

On your component.html template, we bind the `editConfirm` event to another method `onAddClient`

```
<div class="mainTbl">
  <ng2-smart-table 
    [settings]="settMain" 
    [source]="this.Service.clients"
    (createConfirm)="onAddClient($event)"
    (editConfirm)="onEditConfirm($event)"
    (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)"
  ></ng2-smart-table>
</div>
```

On your component.ts,

```
onAddClient(event) {
  this.Service.addClient(event).subscribe(
    (res) => {
      // handle success
    }, (error) => {
     // handle error
    });

}
```

And in addition, on your service.ts, you will pass the data from the compnoent, and return the response from the http request from the HTTP Client.

```
addClient(data){
  console.log(data);
  return this.http.post<Clients>(this.url, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support and illustration after i did as you mention I face another error `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'Subscriber' | property '_subscriptions' -> object with constructor 'Array' | index 0 -> object with constructor 'SubjectSubscription` I think that is because the data need to convert to json but I don't know-how, can you help @wentjun

Comment: Ahh I see.. Wait, but isn't the data in an object or array format? That should be valid JSON